# Feature scaling on null values

Tags: machine-learning, feature-scaling

How to handle null values in dataset for performing feature scaling on a particular column?

i.e.Should we keep the null value as it is or impute some other value?

Is there any tutorial on how to handle null values while feature scaling?

Answer (score 0):

**Scaling** needs every element to be scaled individually. So You can't do feature scaling when you have null values, Thus you need to preprocess your data & I'm suggesting the following options:

1. delete your rows ( I do not recommend it if your data is small )
2. replace it with mean or median …
3. a little bit advanced to use linear regression to predict the
   missing values

Comment: Thanks Oussama Ouardini